# Banach contraction theorem for partially defined maps

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $(f,D(f))$ be a partially defined map on $X$, i.e. $D(f)\subset X$ and
$$
  f:D(f)\to X.
$$
Suppose that $f$ is a contraction, i.e.
$$
  d(f(x),f(y))\leq \rho\cdot d(x,y),\quad \text{for any }x,y\in D(f)
$$
for some $\rho \in [0,1)$ and that there exists a point $x\in D(f)$ such that $f^n(x)\in D(f)$ for any $n=0,1,2,\dots$

Is that true, that the solution of $z = f(z)$ need to exist and be unique? If yes, is it possible to approximate this solution in terms of $f^n(x)$ and $\rho$?

If not, are there any additional assumptions that can guarantee the uniqueness and existence? Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The solution of $z=f(z)$ must be unique if exists (provided that $\rho<1$ is assumed), since if $z_1$ and $z_2$ are both solutions, then $d(z_1,z_2)=d(f(z_1),f(z_2))\not\le\rho\cdot d(z_1,z_2)$.
2. If $f$ is only partial, then the solution needs not exist in this form: let $X$ be the unit disk around the origin and $D(f):=X\setminus\{0\}$ and $f:=x\mapsto \rho\cdot x$ for a $\rho\in (0,1)$.
3. However, if $X$ is *complete*, we can *extend* $D(f)$ in any such case with the limit point of the *Cauchy sequence* starting out from the given $x$:
   $$x_0:=x,\ x_{n+1}:=f(x_n)\,.$$
   (One way to see it's Cauchy is to use 
   $$d(x_0,x_k)\le d(x_0,x_1)\cdot(1+\rho+\rho^2+\dots+\rho^{k-1})\le \frac{d(x_0,x_1)}{1-\rho}=:D$$
   and thus $d(x_N,x_{N+k})\le \rho^N\cdot D $.)